# How to use a variable outside of function?

Tags: javascript, function, callback, asynccallback

Hey guys I'm having trouble using the "appIds" variable outside the function scope, how can this be done? Here's the script below used in NodeJS:

```
var appIds = [];

request("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2?format=json", function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

        var o = JSON.parse(body);
        appIds = o.applist.apps.map(v => v.appid);
        // console.log(appIds); works within scope.
    }
});

console.log(appIds);
```

Answer (score 3):

That is wont work since it is an asynchronous call. You can do only inside the callback.

What you are doing in the commented code is the right way to handle it.

```
request("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2?format=json", function(error, response, body) {
 if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

    var o = JSON.parse(body);
    appIds = o.applist.apps.map(v => v.appid);
    console.log(appIds); //works within scope.
  }
});
```

Comment: I see are there no other way around using it outside the scope? Because the code continues along with a second request which needs to use the results of the first request.

Comment: You have to wrap them one in another. You cannot just go ahead and assuming it. you have fire another request in first request callback.

Comment: You can make the request synchronous and you can then have your bad way of coding work without extra effort.